# Why do the following two ways of showing environment variables of current shell differ?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I found my bash shell's pid

```
$ echo $$
7791
```

I then check its environment variables by two different ways:

```
$ cat /proc/7791/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/532284/156458, 
and

```
$ env
```

However their outputs are not identical. For example they show different values of `PATH`. Why do they differ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should read the comments below that misleading answer.

`/proc/$PID/environ` is not used live by the shell.  It merely represents the process's initial environment when it was launched.

Anything done in the shell, including its init scripts can change those values from within the shell with no change to the `proc` entry you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks. There is comment there, which happens to be my question: for a process, which is not necessary a shell, if its environment variable change, "So, where the new updated environment will stay? Which command to show it?"

Comment: You can examine it in `/proc/$PID/environ` where $PID is the process id of the `env` program. But you will have to be quick, since the `env` process exits pretty quickly.

Comment: @Johan: are you answering my questions? Do you mean the process shall run the `env` program, and at the same time run `/proc/$PID/environ` where `$PID` is the process id of the `env` program?

Comment: My answer was perhaps a bit confusing, sorry. I took the `env` program in your question as an example. Generally, the "environment" of a process is just an array of string=value pair passed to the process in the `envp` argument. The process can do whatever it wants with the values, or ignore them. A **shell** usually collects the values and builds a new vector that is is passed as `envp` to the child process. The file `/proc/$PID/environ` reflects what was passed in the `envp`vector to the process with process id $PID.

Answer (score 5):

`/proc/7791/environ` shows the original environment of the shell, as it was received by the process when it was started using the execve system call:

```
 int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

When the shell is running, it can change its set of exported variables, for example by evaluating `.bashrc`. This new set is then passed in the vector `envp` when the `env`program is started.

Comment: Thanks. For a process, which is not necessary a shell, if its environment variable change, will the new updated environment be stored in some file? Which command to show it?"

Comment: The changes to the enviroment (using `setenv(3)`) are done internally in the process' address space. I don't think there is a tool to inspect the changes from some other process.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever problem you're trying to solve, you could try if using

```
/proc/self
```

solves it. Instead of getting the shell's initial environment, a

```
cat /proc/self/environ
```

displays the environment of the `cat` command, which should be equal to the current environment of the shell it is executed in.